# Image array help in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm Back! And having more Silverlight issues (yay!)

I am trying to create an image array in Silverlight but the images are not appearing on the page. Here is my code:

```
Public imgImages(50) As Image

Public Sub Create_Image_Array()

    Dim I As Integer

    For I = 0 To 50
        imgImages(I) = New Image

        imgImages(I).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, System.Convert.ToDouble(0))
        imgImages(I).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, System.Convert.ToDouble(0))
        imgImages(I).Name = "imgImages" & I

        imgImages(I).Width = System.Convert.ToDouble(18)
        imgImages(I).Height = System.Convert.ToDouble(18)

        imgImages(I).Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("/Resources/yellow2.png", UriKind.Relative))
        imgImages(I).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        AddHandler imgImages(I).MouseLeftButtonUp, AddressOf ImageClickEventProc

    Next I

End Sub

Public Sub Draw_Images()
    For I = 1 To secObject.intNumberOfImages

        imgImages(I).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, System.Convert.ToDouble(secObject.Images(I).intPosX))
        imgImages(I).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, System.Convert.ToDouble(secObject.Images(I).intPosY))
        imgImages(I).Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    Next I
End Sub
```

The image array is created when the page is navigated to and then the page requests location information from a server and once it has that information it sets the X and Y coordinates of the images. All that part works fine - that was apparently the easy part - All the coordinate information is received and stored in secObject, the data is there. The URI for the resource of the image is there and it is valid, I tested it with another image control on the page.

The problem is that the little images are not displaying. I have tried numerous ways of getting them to display. I have found code on Google that does almost the exact same thing that I am trying to do and it is written in a similar way just for non-arrayed images.

I also tried another suggestion, to use TranslateTransform to set the positions of the images. This did nothing.

```
Dim tt As New TranslateTransform

tt.X = secObject.Images(I).intPosX
tt.Y = secObject.Images(I).intPosY
imgImages(I).RenderTransform = tt
```

I also removed the background image on the screen thinking that maybe the images were rendering below the background, and that is not the case.

Am I missing something? I admit to being a Silverlight n00b...

Thanks
-RW

Comment: Silverlight is pretty much dead in the water.

Comment: Silverlight is a pain in the neck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally figured it out... I needed to create add the controls to the canvas:

```
 LayoutRoot.Children.Add(imgImages(I))
```